# I need to insert a value in an input field of an html form through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML code**

```
<div id="formulario">
    <h1>Posicionamento de CEO</h1>
    <form method="POST" style="width: 500px;">   

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label  " for="id_identification">Identificação</label>
        
<div class=" ">enter code here
   <input type="text" name="identification" maxlength="256" class=" form-control" required="" id="id_identification">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label  " for="id_geolocation">Geolocalização</label>
       <div class=" ">
            <input type="text" name="geolocation" maxlength="100" class=" form-control" required="" id="id_geolocation">
</div
        <button type="button" onclick="start()" class="botao">Clique aqui para carregar 
         mapa</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript code that opens the map and captures the coordinate when I click on the map.**

```
async function sendCoordsToMyApi(evt) {
    const coords = {
      lat: evt.latLng.lat(),
      lng: evt.latLng.lng()
    };

    console.log("vou enviar as coordenadas para api:", coords);
    alert(JSON.stringify(coords));
```

I need to enter the coordinate of the constant coords in the form in the input field id="id_geolocation"
can you help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because so is english only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.getElementById to get the element you are trying to add text to

```
coords = ...;
document.getElementById("id_geolocation").value = JSON.stringify(coords);
```

Comment: @RaphaelMaia if the answer works, you should select it as the answer to your question.

Comment: @RaphaelMaia To select, click the check mark next to the number score of the question